# ksh grep for backslash in Linux

Tags: linux, date, ksh, backslash

I have a file that has a date in the format of `MM\DD\YYYY` at the end of each line.  After that part of the file there is some text at the end that I don't want.  I don't want to use tail in case the number of lines of text at the end should change. I just want to get all the lines that have a date at the end.

I've tried various forms of `grep` including `grep "[0-9]\\\\[0-9]\\\\[0-9]" file.txt` or even just `grep "\\\\[0-9]" file.txt` and no matter how I try escaping the backslash the `grep` doesn't work.

I can just `grep` for `"[0-9$]"` and that seems to pull the lines, but I'd prefer to be able to include the slashes.  I'm using Korn shell.   Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ksh Regular Expressions

Ksh has it's own regular expressions. 
Use an * for any string. So to get all the files ending with .c use *.c. 
A single character is represented with a ?. So all the files starting with any sign followed bye 44.f can be fetched by: ?44.f.

Especially in ksh there are quantifiers for whole patterns:

?(pattern) matches zero or one times the pattern.
*(pattern) matches any time the pattern.
+(pattern) matches one or more time the pattern.
@(pattern) matches one time the pattern.
!(pattern) matches string without the pattern.

So one can question a string in a variable like: if [[ $var = fo@(?4*67).c ]];then ...

Reference **[here](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#regexp)**.
Maybe **[this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)** will also help.

EDIT:

See if this works for you:

```
grep '[[:digit:]]\{2\}\\[[:digit:]]\{2\}\\[[:digit:]]\{4\}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I tried your solution and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempy only look for 1 digit

```
grep "[0-9]\\\\[0-9]\\\\[0-9]" file.txt # wrong, looks for only 1 digit between 2 \
```

try intead:

```
grep '[0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9]' file.txt
```

Now if the date is always mm\dd\yyyy and at the end of the line, you should grep:

```
grep '[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' file.txt
```

an example of treatment:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/___&___/' < file.txt
```

will display the file, and place "___" before and after the dates at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the grep commands, but they still didn't work.  I get nothing as output. sed command gave me an error.  Unterminated s command.  Don't want quotes around the dates, though.  Just want all lines that have a date at the end of the line.

Comment: the s command is terminated in my example. the use of single or double quotes is important for the commands. to preserve the right amount of arguments and also sometime to protect the interpretations of spaces and special chars. just copy the whole line & paste it.

Comment: a possibility is that there is something after the dste , l (spaces? or a ^M If you trear on linux a file created on windows?). in that case, drop the "$" (end of line anchor) ans thus do : `sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/___&___/g' < file.txt` (replaces the date (s) anywhere on the line. i removed the $ and also added g to allow multiple replace)